# how to connect to a database which is located in a local server in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, networking

I need to **access** my **database** which is located in University **central server**. University gave me the **ip address**  and also **root access** and the **password**. *I don't Have the port address*,i know to connect to a database with port address like this,i Used this Connection String to connect multiple computers and it works,but Want to connect my database through the univercity server

```
Data Source=192.168.1.1,2222\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Temp_project;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password
```

University server is using => **linux , Cenos**
My software is Running on => **Windows**
Mysql Server is => **phpMyAdmin**
Server ip is =>**10.10.10.XX**
username=>root
password=>**XXXXX**

[**this is my Connection String in C#**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43O1e.png)
[**this is the error what i get**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZNCG.png)

```
public string datastring = ("Server=10.10.10.XX;Database=tmsdatabase;Uid=root;Pwd=XXXXX;");
```

***What i'm Asking is  to solution to  my Error............***

***Thank you..........***
[**OK i open the connection and nothing changed**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHdzv.png)

Comment: con.open() before da.fill()

Comment: Just making sure here, 10.x.x.x is internal IP, so your computer is connected to university network/VPN, right? Also, can you ping the IP from your computer console?

Comment: yes i can access  and also i can access the database from phpmyadmin using the given ip ,username,password ,i created the database inside the server using phpmyadmin by myself

Answer (score 0):

You didn open the connection.
You have to use `con.Open();` so you can establish the connection to the database.
and you have to close the connection as well after you finish your readings with `con.Close()`.
Also you have to put everything in try catch block so your code should be

```
 MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(dataString);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            (rest of your code)
            con.Close()
        }
        catch 
        {
          (something went wrong)
          con.Close();
        }
```

EDIT: I don't know if in your connection string you put the port as well. In your first code you have

```
Data Source=192.168.1.1,2222\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Temp_project;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password
```

That's the correct format of a connection string.

Comment: error is not about the open connection ,it is about  unable to connect to the mysql host ,real problem is server and the software is not calling to each other because server is running on **linux** and my software is running on windows thats the  problem

Comment: i need to make them talk